# what should a dealer say when a player places a bet after the river card, and all other players fold?

Tags: terminology, dealer

As a dealer:  player A places a bet after the river card, and all other players fold.
what should I say while passing the pot chips to player A ?

in italian is "respinto", I wonder if it is "rejected" in English, meaning that all other players refused to call the bet

Answer (score 1):

You say nothing, and push the pot to the winning player, as with all other hands. There is no need to announce what is obvious and clear.

You may wish to hesitate in case a player has missed their action, hidden their cards, and somehow has a winning hand. Given how unlikely it is, asking whether someone still has cards would be much more likely to delay the game and deflate the winner's victory than make it smoother and ensure accurate awards of a pot.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you say anything? I feel like this is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). If there are no callers, the pot is won by the player placing the only bet that was not matched and the pot goes to them. A video game implementation would probably have a message like "No callers" or "Everyone folds". You're not an NPC, so you don't really need to announce things that the players already know on a table, assuming they know the rules of poker. If you're teaching poker, then that's another story and you should say things relative to the knowledge of everyone else.

Answer (score -3):

If everybody else folds, you’re the winner.

Comment: hopefully "thank you."